# Lambda expression as parameter to be used as AsTask() callback

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm using the BackgroundTransfer.DownloadOperation in a method and I want the caller to be able to pass a lambda expression to be called when progress is updated:

```
DownloadOperation dwo = await DownloadFile(fileInfo,file);
```

This works:

```
var progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(DefaultProgressCallback);
await dwo.StartAsync().AsTask(progressCallback);
```

But how do I define a lambda parameter to be able to do this?

```
var progressCallback = lambdaFromMethodCaller;
await dwo.StartAsync().AsTask(progressCallback);
```

Comment: lambda parameter is `Func` read about this -> `Func<T1, ReturnType>` if you want more parameters `Func<T1,T2,...,ReturnType>`

Comment: @wudzik I tried 'Func<DownloadOperation>' as parameter but I get:


Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Progress<Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.DownloadOperation>' to 'System.Func<Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.DownloadOperation>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779751.aspx) extension method you use does not contain a signature that accepts delegate/Func, so you can't do `.AsTask(...=>...)`

But you can use lambda in this line:

```
var progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(...=>...);
```

Since the constructor of [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160061.aspx) accepts an `Action<T>`